# Python - convert values if column and row names are the same

Tags: python, dataframe, intersection

I have a df as below - what I want to do is to convert `1` to `0` if ONLY the column names are equal to row names.

print(df)

```
         name  seq102681  seq103  seq11
0     seq102681     1       0      0
1      seq103       0       1      0
2       seq11       1       1      1
```

the desired output should be:

```
         name  seq102681  seq103  seq11
0     seq102681     0       0      0
1      seq103       0       0      0
2       seq11       1       1      0
```

I tried using intersection but it does not work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

intersection = df.index & df.columns
for item in intersection:
    df.loc[item, item] = 0
print(df)
```

`Note:` there are sometimes multiple rows with the same name but all of the column names are unique.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
col_list = list(df.columns)
col_list.remove('name')

for col in col_list:
  df.loc[df['name'] == col, col] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

in fact, you want to change the diagonal of dataframe (Matrix). so you can use this code:

```
df.values[[np.arange(df.shape[0])]*2] = 0
```

you can do this using `Numpy` also:

```
import numpy as np
np.fill_diagonal(df.values, 0)
```

Comment: it is not always diagonal - there are sometimes multiple rows with the same name but all of the column names are unique.

Answer (score 1):

```
   for col in df.columns:
        df.loc[df['name'] == col, col] = 0
```

Comment: If there happens to be a row where the value of name is 'name' then that will be set to 0 which I think is meant to be an excluded case (My solution is same as yours with that minor edge case handled)